# PHP sending headers in message copy

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to use PHP to send and HTML formated email. I've been trouble shooting but  here is my test code:

```
$email ="
<html> 
  <body> 
    <p style=\"text-align:center;height:100px;background-color:#abc;border:1px solid #456;border-radius:3px;padding:10px;\">
        <b>I am receiving HTML email</b>
        <br/><br/><br/><a style=\"text-decoration:none;color:#246;\" href=\"www.example.com\">example</a>
    </p>
    <br/><br/>Now you Can send HTML Email
  </body>
</html>";


$emailaddress = "personsemail@website.com";
$subject = "Test Email";
$headers = "From: noreply@server.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";


mail($emailaddress, $subject, $email, $headers);
```

The FROM header works, but the email doesn't display as HTML, instead i get plain text that looks like this:

```
Content-type: text/html
Message-Id: <randomnumber@servername.hostingprovidor.com>
Date: Tue, 28 Apr 2015 12:45:48 -0500 (EST)


<html>
  <body>
    <p style="text-align:center;height:100px;background-color:#abc;border:1px solid #456;border-radius:3px;padding:10px;">
        <b>I am receiving HTML email</b>
        <br/><br/><br/><a style="text-decoration:none;color:#246;" href="www.example.com">example</a>
    </p>
    <br/><br/>Now you Can send HTML Email
  </body>
</html>
```

is this a server setting problem? Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is what you would get if you had an extra `\r\n` between the `From` and `Content-type` headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a couple more headers in order to display the email content as html, try this instead:

```
$email = <<< LOL
<html> 
  <body> 
    <p style="text-align:center;height:100px;background-color:#abc;border:1px solid #456;border-radius:3px;padding:10px;">
        <b>I am receiving HTML email</b>
        <br/><br/><br/><a style="text-decoration:none;color:#246;" href="www.example.com">example</a>
    </p>
    <br/><br/>Now you Can send HTML Email
  </body>
</html>
LOL;

$emailaddress = "personsemail@website.com";
$subject = "Test Email";
$headers = "From: noreply@server.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


mail($emailaddress, $subject, $email, $headers);
```

Comment: His original code was fine, he would have gotten a syntax error if the quotes were wrong. He escaped the embedded quotes.

Comment: @dprogramz If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the correct answer by clicking the check mark int the middle of the vote arrows. Tks !

Answer (score 1):

You should probably set a MIME type in your header.  Try this:

```
$headers = 'From: noreply@server.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: That wouldn't cause the headers to be put into the body. BTW, why do you switch back and forth between single and double quotes like that?

Comment: Generally, I try to keep string literals inside of single quotes.  However, I've seen issues where the line breaks don't work right if they are in string literals, particularly in mail headers.  I've always broken the line endings off into double quotes by themselves for this reason.  Could be part of the problem here.

Comment: Of course the line breaks don't work right in single quotes. Escape sequences are only recognized in double quotes. But there's nothing wrong with putting the whole literal in double quotes, `"foo\r\n"`

Comment: Right, it is more for clarity's sake and to help avoid accidents.  That's probably why it is done this way in the example documentation for the PHP mail() documentation page http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php